# How does TXID gets created and at which point

Tags: transaction-id

I see TxID in bitcoin transaction input as reference of the UTXO. How does TXID gets created and at which point, wallet or node?

Answer (score 2):

The TXID, the transaction ID, is a hash of the serialized (non-witness) transaction whose UTXO is being spent. It gets created at the same time as the transaction does

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So what gets broadcast on network, Only TxID or both TxID and serialized entire transaction? I believe second.

Comment: You only need to send the serialized transaction itself, because anyone can hash it to find the txid. But generally the txid would be sent first so the client can see if they already have it or not